# How to group my List<> into categories

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this following class:

```
public class TV
{
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have this following list (which is dynamic created and will never be same):

```
List<TV> myList = new List<TV>();
myList.Add(new TV { GroupId = "1", Title = "Title 1", Genre = "Genre A" });
myList.Add(new TV { GroupId = "1", Title = "Title 2", Genre = "Genre A" });
myList.Add(new TV { GroupId = "1", Title = "Title 3", Genre = "Genre A" });
myList.Add(new TV { GroupId = "3", Title = "Title 4", Genre = "Genre 18" });
myList.Add(new TV { GroupId = "A", Title = "Title 5", Genre = "Genre 18" });
myList.Add(new TV { GroupId = "A", Title = "Title 6", Genre = "Genre A" });
myList.Add(new TV { GroupId = "B", Title = "Title 7", Genre = "Genre A" });
myList.Add(new TV { GroupId = "C", Title = "Title 8", Genre = "Genre A" });
myList.Add(new TV { GroupId = "D", Title = "Title 9", Genre = "Genre 18" });
myList.Add(new TV { GroupId = "D", Title = "Title 10", Genre = "Genre A" });
myList.Add(new TV { GroupId = "D", Title = "Title 11", Genre = "Genre A" });
myList.Add(new TV { GroupId = "E", Title = "Title 12", Genre = "Genre A" });
```

I have the following (hardcoded) navigation categories that are links:

> [0-9] [ABC] [DEF] [GHI] [JKL] [MNO] [PQR] [STU] [VWXYZ]

I’m trying to loop myList and by looking at the **GroupId** property, I want to place it in the appropriate div so I end up having divs like this:

```
<div id="group-09">
<div>
    1, Title 1, Genre A
    1, Title 2, Genre A
    1, Title 3, Genre A
    3, Title 4, Genre 18
</div>
</div>

<div id="group-ABC">
<div>
    A, Title 5, Genre 18
    A, Title 6, Genre A
    B, Title 7, Genre A
    C, Title 8, Genre A
</div>
</div>

<div id="group-DEF">
<div>
    D, Title 9, Genre 18
    D, Title 10, Genre A
    D, Title 11, Genre A
    E, Title 12, Genre A
</div>
</div>
```

I can’t seem to figure out the logic to properly do this!
Does anyone have a suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary that maps `GroupId`s to `<div>` ids and group the items in `myList` by `<div>` id:

```
var groups = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "0", "group-09" },
    { "1", "group-09" },
    { "2", "group-09" },
    ...
    { "A", "group-ABC" },
    ...
};

var query = from item in myList
            group item by groups[item.GroupId];

foreach (var group in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("id: " + group.Key);
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("       " + item.Title);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - far more concise and featured than my feeble half assed attempt :)

Comment: I’ve decided to go along with your mapping dictionary approach. Works great! I also like the different approaches proposed by the others, there is some great ideas behind them. Thanks to all!

Comment: True, I like the Regex approach unfortunately, I didn’t get the chance to try it out since I only came back on SO this pm to give an answer. Perhaps I’ll refactor…

Answer (score 2):

```
public string GetGroupFamilyId(string groupId) {
   if (groupId >= "A" && groupId <="C") return "ABC";
   .....
   //or implement it somehow, implementation does not matter, the idea does
}

....

var groupedResult = myList
                      .GroupBy(x=>GetGroupFamilyId(x));
```

Looks like that's all you need...

Answer (score 1):

Using [**Regex**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx):

```
        string key = "[0-9] [ABC] [DEF] [GHI] [JKL] [MNO] [PQR] [STU] [VWXYZ]";
        string[] keyes = key.Split(' ');

        Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<TV>> groups = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<TV>>();

        foreach (var pattern in keyes)
        {
            Regex reg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            groups.Add(pattern, myList.Where(x => reg.IsMatch(x.GroupId)));
        }
```

Here's the parsing of the DIV's too:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var group in groups.Where(x => x.Value.Any()))
        {
            sb.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, "<div id=\"group-{0}\">\n\t<div>", group.Key.Split(new char[] { '[', ']'})[1]);

            foreach (var tv in group.Value)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, "\n\t\t{0}", tv.ToString());
            }
            sb.AppendFormat("\n\t</div>\n</div>\n\n");
        }
```

Sample Output:

```
<div id="group-0-9">
    <div>       
        1, Title 1, Genre A     
        1, Title 2, Genre A     
        1, Title 3, Genre A     
        3, Title 4, Genre 18
    </div>
</div>
<div id="group-ABC">
    <div>       
        A, Title 5, Genre 18        
        A, Title 6, Genre A     
        B, Title 7, Genre A     
        C, Title 8, Genre A
    </div>
</div>
<div id="group-DEF">
    <div>       
        D, Title 9, Genre 18        
        D, Title 10, Genre A        
        D, Title 11, Genre A        
        E, Title 12, Genre A
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1st angle to attack is getting everything into a grouped object:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, TV>> newGroup = myList.GroupBy(x => x.GroupId);
```

then, you can concatanate lists together based on your arbitary groups `[abc]` etc:

```
var listABC = newGroup.Where(y => 
                y.Key.Contains("A") 
                || y.Key.Contains("B") 
                || y.Key.Contains("C"));
```

better ways exist, but it's one to ponder...